# JavaFX console service with GUI

Tags: javafx-2

I need to make an application that runs as a server that accepts connections from various clients and responds to their requests (via proprietary protocol). This server also needs a GUI for configuration and monitoring. I (of course) need to run the server as a service, and the GUI has to be available only at certain moments. Since the server service and GUI share some of the hardware resources and part of the configuration they would run on the same machine. I would like that the GUI and the whole long running service are one process that will run in the background; the GUI would than be invoked (shown) only when needed.

My question is: can this be done with a JavaFX 2 GUI and how?

Thanks in advance
Josip

Answer (score 0):

So you need Monitoring and Management in a Java application? You should be using the Java Management Extensions (JMX) Technology. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/overview.html

And if you decide that you can't just use a standard JMX client or create a plugin then you create your JavaFX application as a JMX client.

Comment: Actually it seems that JMX could be the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe RMI would be better suited than JMX because the GUI is not used exactly for monitoring but for executing procedures on the server. The server is the only process connected to the remote hardware and performs some actions on the hardware automatically, but there are some actions that have to be initiated from a GUI by a user. Do you think RMI would be better, I guess I can do the same things with JMX that I can do with RMI?